# Generic HashMap does not implement method get

Tags: rust

I am trying to create generic structure that will contain lots of generic typed fields. AST of this structure will be generated by the compiler plugin and will be used for rendering text from template.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::string::ToString;


pub struct Context<Key, Value>
    where Value: ToString
{
    value: HashMap<Key, Value>,
    // here will be other fields with different generic types
}


impl <Key, Value> Context <Key, Value>
    where Value: ToString
{
    // In Jinja2 this can be written like
    // `some text before ... {{ value["foobar"] }} ... text after`
    pub fn render_to_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut r = String::new();
        r.push_str("text before ... ");

        // We see that the type of key is &'static str.
        // It is easy to determine when code written manually by human.
        // But such code will be generated by compiler plugin.
        // Here can be integer or another field from &self
        // instead of static string.
        self.value.get(&("foobar")).map(|v: &Value| r.push_str(&v.to_string()));

        r.push_str(" ... text after");
        r
    }
}


fn main() {
    let ctx1 = Context {
        value: {
            let mut v = HashMap::new();
            v.insert("foobar", 123u64);
            v
        },
    };
    println!("{:?}", ctx1.render_to_string());
}
```

Unfortunately Rust refuses to compile code with such fuzzy types, but instead of telling what traits should be defined for generics it outputs:

```
<anon>:25:20: 25:36 error: type `std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<Key, Value>` does not implement any method in scope named `get`
<anon>:25         self.value.get(&("foobar")).map(|v: &Value| r.push_str(&v.to_string()));
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can this code will be fixed without specifying exact types of `Key` and `Value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check out the [type signature of `get`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get):

```
impl<K, V, S> HashMap<K, V, S>
    where K: Eq + Hash,
          S: HashState
{
    fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> 
        where K: Borrow<Q>,
              Q: Hash + Eq
    {}
}
```

All of those conditions need to be true for the `get` method to be available. Specifically, in your case, you need for the `Key` to be `Eq + Hash`:

```
impl <Key, Value> Context <Key, Value>
    where Key: Eq + std::hash::Hash,
          Value: ToString
```

This leads to a new error, because you are using a `&str` as the key to get, so you really have to specify that a `&str` *can* be used as a key:

```
impl<Key, Value> Context <Key, Value>
    where Key: Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::borrow::Borrow<str>,
          Value: ToString
```

Then, remove the reference from your `get` line:

```
self.value.get("foobar")
```

> So, path `std::borrow::Borrow<str>` strictly specifies that we know the real type of key at code generation stage.

It does **not** specify you know the real type of the key. It only requires that whatever your key is, a `&str` can be borrowed from a `&Key`. For example, your `Key` could be a `String` or a `CowString`. This is required because you are using `"foobar"` as the key.

> [The key] can be integer or another field from &self instead of static string.

If it's another member of self, then you could parameterize the struct appropriately:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::string::ToString;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub struct Context<Key, Value> {
    value: HashMap<Key, Value>,
    key: Key,
}

impl <Key, Value> Context <Key, Value>
    where Key: Eq + Hash,
          Value: ToString,
{
    pub fn render_to_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut r = "text before ... ".to_string();

        self.value.get(&self.key).map(|v| r.push_str(&v.to_string()));

        r.push_str(" ... text after");
        r
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ctx1 = Context {
        key: 42,
        value: {
            let mut v = HashMap::new();
            v.insert(42, 123u64);
            v
        },
    };
    println!("{:?}", ctx1.render_to_string());
}
```

> to force Rust to resolve key type at first self.value.get call

This sounds like you want dynamic (runtime) typing - which doesn't exist. Rust is a statically-typed language, so types must be determined at compile time.

If you have a fixed set of key types, you could simply create an enum:

```
enum Key {
    String(String),
    Int(i32),
}
```

And then use that instead of a generic.

Comment: So, path `std::borrow::Borrow<str>` strictly specifies that we know the real type of key at code generation stage. Can it be replaced with something like `std::borrow::Borrow<AnotherGeneric>` to force Rust to resolve key type at first `self.value.get` call? (Code generator guarantees that each field of Context will be accessed at least once).

Comment: @werehuman I've attempted to answer your questions. I don't understand why you mention "*guarantees that each field of Context will be accessed at least once*" - what effect will that have on the problem?

Comment: Why is the hashmap's generic type signature specify keys have to be `Eq + Hash`, but get's type signature specifies keys can be `?Static + Eq + Hash` ?

Comment: @minseong [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) says nothing about "static" and `?Static` isn't valid Rust syntax.

Comment: @Shepmaster I meant `?Sized` instead of `?Static`